# How can I tell whether my system is Unix or Linux?

Tags: linux

How can I tell whether my system is Unix or Linux?

I am using a Macbook Pro of 2010 vintage.

Comment: How much did you pay for it?

Comment: There are (at least) four different definitions of the term "Unix": 1) the series of operating system(s) by Bell Labs, 2) the family of operating systems derived from the source code of 1), 3) any operating system that has passed certification by The Open Group (or 3a) any operating system that would pass certification by The Open Group but can't afford the certification fee), 4) any operating system that looks and feels like "Unix". For example, with the exception of specialized distributions like Android, most Linux distributions fall under 4), some under 3a), and a few under 3).

Comment: OTOH, even though OSX falls under 2) and 3), I would argue that it doesn't fall under 4). Windows NT, at least in some versions, satisfies 3), but definitely not 4).

Answer (score 18):

POSIX defines [`uname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/uname.html) ("Unix name") to provide information about the operating system and hardware platform; running `uname` gives the name of the implementation of the operating system (or according to the `coreutils` documentation, the kernel). You can do this interactively in a terminal, or use the output in a script.

On Linux systems, `uname` will print `Linux`.

On Mac OS X systems, `uname` will print `Darwin`. (Strictly speaking, any operating system with a Darwin kernel will produce this, but you're very unlikely to encounter anything other than Mac OS X in this case.)

This will allow you to determine what any Mac is running. As [Rob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3887/rob) points out, if you're running Mac OS X (`Darwin` as indicated by `uname`), then you're running a [certified version of Unix](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/); if you're running Linux then you're not.

On a Mac there are many other possibilities; your script could end up running on Solaris (`uname` will print `SunOS` then), on FreeBSD (`FreeBSD`), on Windows with Cygwin (`CYGWIN`), MSYS or MSYS2 (`MSYS`), a MinGW or MinGW-w64 shell (`MINGW64`, `MINGW32`), Interix (`Interix`), and probably others I'm not aware of.

`uname -a` will print all the available information as determined by `uname`, but it's harder to parse.

Comment: The problem is, uname does not prove it is running Unix. It only gives a name of the OS which might not be a Unix system. Linux, for example, is not Unix.

Comment: @Rob, nowhere did either Stéphane or I say that; in fact we're explicitly differentiating between Linux and Unix (or rather Mac OS X).

Answer (score 3):

Unless you installed something else, Macs don't run Linux. Macbooks do run Apple's operating system called [OSX which is certified Unix](http://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/) and, therefore, is the answer to your question.

Comment: Of course, some versions of Linux are also certified Unix, so the question then becomes, is it running Linux or Unix?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I see that the only version of Linux that is certified as Unix is an LDAP server running SUSE from IBM, but no others are or ever have been or probably ever will. my answer remains the same, though. If he didn't install Linux on a Mac then he's running OSX which is Unix.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

```
uname -a
```

Or:

```
cat /proc/version
```

Comment: Open a terminal window and type 'uname -a' then return.

Comment: What can I deduce about the OS if `cat /proc/version` produce the error message `cat: /proc/version: No such file or directory`?

Comment: Look it /etc/fstab, look at the file types indicated there. If it is like ext3, ext4, xfs, it is linux. If it is like jfs, gpfs, hfs, hfs+, that is unix.

Comment: If you see `xfs` it could be IRIX ;-). (But not on a Mac, I'll give you that!)